# Failed building wheel for dm-tree

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, pip

I tried installing keras but I am getting the following error
[The picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERELR.png)

I tried installing keras but got errors.
I have also installed wheel.
I am also not able to install tensorflow.
python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.

Comment: Please post the complete error message begining at the word *Traceback*. Post as text not image or links.

Answer (score 1):

At first I installed Python version 3.12 and had same these problems. Then I reinstalled Python version 3.11 and it works

Comment: Is this the only fix?

Answer (score 0):

It does say you have to have CMake installed to build it.
Are you sure you have it?
You should write `cmake --version` in cmd or something to check in case you are not sure.
You might have to install nmake then too if you arre doing this on windows.